# Have realtime updates for a single Firestore document

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

There is a lot of documentation and examples of firestore collections getting realtime updates. However, there is very little for those who wish to have a single document have real time updates. I want to have a single document (an `item`), on a page where only the `item` will be viewed and manipulated and any changes to document, will have realtime updating.

Here is my component that wants to do stuff with the `item`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ItemsService } from '../shared/items.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-view-item',
  templateUrl: './view-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./view-item.component.css']
})
export class ViewItem implements OnInit {
  item;
  private sub: any;

  constructor(
    // Service used for Firebase calls
    private itemsService: ItemsService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // Item retrieved from */item/:id url
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.getItem(params['id']);
    });
  }

  getItem = (id) => {
    this.itemsService.getItem(id).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.item = res;
      console.log(this.item);
    });
  }
```

And the service it uses for calls:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ItemsService {
  constructor(
    private firestore: AngularFirestore
  )

  getItem(id) {
    return this.firestore.collection('items').doc(id).snapshotChanges();
  }
}
```

The log I get for `console.log(this.item)` is `undefined`. Calling `this.item` in the console returns the same. I am unsure of how to proceed and would appreciate any guidance. Logging `res` in the console returns a byzantine object. Perhaps that's how I access the `item`, but if so, why is it not saved in `this.item` and how do I access the `item`'s values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`snapshotChanges` returns an *observable of actions*, **not** the actual value.
You should extract the value with `action.payload.doc.data()`:

So your code should look like the following example.

```
getItem(id) {
  return this.firestore.collection('items').doc(id).snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(
      map(actions => actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data();
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      })
    );
}
```

Or you can use `valueChanges` of `doc`.

```
getItem(id) {
  return this.firestore.collection('items').doc(id).valueChanges();
}
```

Comment: Tried the second option and it does work! But I get `undefined` whenever I attempt to access `this.item` outside of the `subscribe` call. Any idea why that may be?

Comment: You defined the getItem as an arrow function. `getItem = (id) => {}`. Why don't you change it to `getItem(id) {}`?

Comment: Hmm, tried that but I still  get `undefined` when I try to access `this.item` outside of
`subscribe()`

Comment: Ah, I see. `subscribe` executes after all of the sync code.